# Remove / backslash from query to get valid data in oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

With my latest query, I get the data as `ABDD_1037/`. but I don't want the record which has `/` in it.

I tried with below query but it's not working

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID) AS SPAN_ID, 
       TO_CHAR(RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE) AS  MAINT_ZONE_CODE
  FROM NE.MV_SPAN@DB_LINK_NE_VIEWER
                  --   FROM  APP_FTTX.span@SAT
 WHERE LENGTH(RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID) > 8 
   AND LENGTH(RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID) < 21            
   AND INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = 'IPL' 
   AND RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = 'INUEABDD01'
   AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE (RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID,'_(9|31|4|7|_____|U|[\/]$)','i')
 MINUS         
SELECT TO_CHAR(LINK_ID) AS SPAN_ID,
       TO_CHAR(MAINTENANCEZONECODE) AS MAINT_ZONE_CODE
  FROM TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS
 WHERE SPAN_TYPE = 'INTRACITY'
   AND MAINTENANCEZONECODE = 'INUEABDD01'
 ORDER BY 1;
```

**UPDATE**

IF I comment the whole regex line, I would get all the unwanted data like below

```
`ABDD_0102_U`, `ABDD_1037/`,`ABDD_3102`, `ABDD_4003`, `STHU_9032`,
```

Comment: I think you can remove the last `/` inside brackets in your regexp pattern.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai: Please help how to remove that in regex pattern.!!! I tried but it's not working

Comment: I didn't see the NOT operator you are using with regexp.

Comment: You don't want a value that has `/` in it at all; or as the last character; or as the only character after underscore, which is what you're looking for at the moment? (Incidentally `[\/]` will match either of those characters, it isn't escaping the `/` if that was your intent. And underscores aren't wildcards so `_____` looks odd.) Maybe explain what you are trying to get the whole regex to do, with examples of what should and shouldn't match.

Comment: @AlexPoole: With above of my regex, I have excluded most of the unwanted things like `_` , `character which ends with 9`, `character which ends with U` till here I was able to achieve it. but when I tried to escape `/` in existing regex it is not working

Comment: @hud - the only 'ends with' at the moment is if it ends with `_/` or `_<backslash>`. For the rest you're excluding anything that contains `_9`, `_31`, `_U`, or `______` anywhere, not just at the end. Which might be what you want but doesn't seem to match your comment. Maybe the `$` was supposed to be after the `)`? This is why explaining (in the question) what the whole thing is supposed to do would be helpful...

Comment: @AlexPoole: please look at my updated question, with my regex i removed all the unwanted things, in that I want to remove `/` also

Comment: @AlexPoole: I don't want a value that has `/` in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment your pattern:

```
'_(9|31|4|7|_____|U|[\/]$'
```

will match any value which contains `_9`, `_31`, `_4`, `_7`, `______` (six underscores), `_U` or `_u` anywhere; or which ends with `_/` (or `_<backslash>`, which I don't think you intended).

If you want it to match values ending with `_<someting>/` then you need to allow for the <something> part, e.g.:

```
'_(9|31|4|7|_____|U|.*/$)'
```

If you want it to match values with a `/` in it anywhere, not just at the end and following an underscore, then you need to separate that from the underscore prefix and remove the $ anchor, e.g.:

```
'(_(9|31|4|7|_____|U)|/)'
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4d72b7be39995404d2d8b21cb4502036)

Comment: yes, now I got it how it works. Thanks Alex for explanation on regex.